# How do I remove the Xerox printer icon from the task bar?

Tags: printer, taskbar, boot, icons

I once installed a driver for a Xerox Phaser 6110 printer.

Ever since, I have a printer icon in my task bar whenever I restart the computer. Right-clicking it brings up the option to "Exit" which removes it, but I can't find where to remove it, or disable it. It should be noted that this has no effect on printing itself, so I don't really need it.

I've gone over the services, and through msconfig, but have found nothing.

I'd like the icon not to be there when the computer is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found it.

1. Go to Start Menu's "Xerox Phaser 6110" -> "Maintenance".
2. Run the "Repair" option.
3. Take care to remove the checkbox from the "Status Monitor" option

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for the app starting in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup or C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Start Menu\Programs\Startup?  Naturally this assumes your default install is on C.

I would have thought you would find this through MSCONFIG but...

Keep in mind they sometimes use some unusual names for the app or service

Comment: Nothing there...